# Does iOS prompt for an Apple ID password after a device has been turned off for a certain period of time?

Tags: ios, apple-id

One of my family members has an iPhone that up until several days ago hadn't been turned on for at least 6 months. When booting the phone, they were met with the Activation Lock screen and asked to enter the password for their Apple ID; I physically saw this screen, so know that it wasn't the standard iOS prompt that asks for the Apple ID password after an update, etc. I immediately assumed that this meant that the device had been erased due to too many incorrect passcode attempts; however, after entering the correct password for the Apple ID, the standard Home Screen was displayed along with all of the content that was present on the device before it had been turned off those months earlier.

So - my question. Does iOS automatically prompt for its linked Apple ID password after being turned off for a certain period of time?